# How to change proxy of a ChromeDriver instance?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

The only way to set proxy on ChromeDriver I see is by passing it through options when constructing. I'm trying to reuse ChromeDriver instances, but they need different proxies. How do I change proxy of a ChromeDriver instance?